# Lex parser: (end of buffer or a NUL) segfault

Tags: c++, parsing, bison, lex, flex-lexer

I have been experiencing segmentation fault problem problem with the lex parser written. Therefore i have added in debugging switch -d to the Makefile when building my program.
This is the output I get from it.

```
--accepting rule at line 180 ("bxz")
--accepting rule at line 61 (" ")
--accepting rule at line 180 ("e")
--accepting rule at line 68 ("
")
--accepting rule at line 180 ("0L")
--accepting rule at line 193 ("!")
--accepting rule at line 68 ("
")
--accepting rule at line 180 ("0x")
--accepting rule at line 193 (""")
--accepting rule at line 68 ("
")
--(end of buffer or a NUL)
Segmentation fault
```

When I run this through a debugging tool, I found that the error occur at yy_get_next_buffer () at lex.yy.c:1324 which is the C file automatically generated from my handcoded lex file. How can I resolve this issue? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is unlikely that the bug is in the lex code. Therefore it sounds like you are writing off the end of a buffer or abusing memory incorrectly in some other way. Valgrind may help in finding memory errors.

Comment: try to put a newline after your last tokenstring. It might be that your parser tries to find some terminating character after the last symbol.

Comment: You've probably corrupted flex's internal buffer pointer somehow, by writing off the end of an array or some such.  If you look at the lex code that is crashing, you might be able to put a data breakpoint on the datastructure that has the incorrect data and figure out who is modifying it

Answer (score 0):

(I flagged this as "not reproducible", [however it timed-out/aged away](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287165/why-were-my-older-close-flags-aged-away). [It has been answered in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments).)

@LokiAstari wrote:

> It is unlikely that the bug is in the lex code. Therefore it sounds like you are writing off the end of a buffer or abusing memory incorrectly in some other way. Valgrind may help in finding memory errors

@AK wrote:

> try to put a newline after your last tokenstring. It might be that your parser tries to find some terminating character after the last symbol.

@ChrisDodd wrote:

> You've probably corrupted flex's internal buffer pointer somehow, by writing off the end of an array or some such. If you look at the lex code that is crashing, you might be able to put a data breakpoint on the datastructure that has the incorrect data and figure out who is modifying it